# Ways to mock Camel Endpoint POJO producer

Tags: java, apache-camel

I followed guide [here](http://camel.apache.org/pojo-producing.html), and I was successfully able to configure a producer on my bean endpoint like this:

```
@Produce( uri = "activemq:foo" )
  private MyListener myListener;
```

`MyListener` is:

```
public interface MyListener {

  @InOnly
  public void send( String message );
}
```

and my bean:

```
    public class MyBeanEndpoint {

          @Produce( uri = "activemq:foo" )
          private MyListener myListener; 

          @Handler
          public void doSomething( final Object body ) {
            ...
    }

public void setMyListener( final MyListener myListener ) {
    this.myListener = myListener;
  }
```

Now, how can I test this?
I mean: my test extends `CamelTestSupport` and I configured my routes with

```
@Override
  public RouteBuilder createRouteBuilder() {
    return new RouteBuilder() { ... }
```

That is: I've reproduced camel context, but I've NO spring context configured and I want (if possible) to avoid instantiating it.

How can I mock producer or make Camel instantiate and inject this bean into my bean endpoint?
What is the best way to test such situation using Apache Camel features like `CamelTestSupport` and similar utilities?

My reference test is:

```
public class Test extends CamelTestSupport {

  private static BeanEndpoint beanEndpoint

  @BeforeClass
  public static void init() { 
    beanEndpoint.setActivemqMyListener( ??? );
  }

  @Override
  public CamelContext createCamelContext() {
    context = new DefaultCamelContext();
    context.addComponent( "activemq", new SedaComponent() );
    return context;
  }

  @Override
  public RouteBuilder createRouteBuilder() {
    return new RouteBuilder() {

      @Override
      public void configure() throws Exception {

        from( "activemq:foo" )
                .to( "mock:out" );

      }
    };
  }

  @Test
  public void testFooQueue() throws Exception {}
```

Comment: How do you create your `my bean` ? You would need some dependency injection to inject that listener,

Comment: Hi, yes I inject successfully through spring context this bean. My question is: how can I UNIT test it?
Is there a way to mock such producer, avoiding dependency injection and manually injecting a producer mock object (that is what I'm looking for) or do I have to instantiate also a spring test context to test it?

Comment: what do you want, to change the endpoint to not send to activemq?

Comment: More or less, I added my test code in the question. I would make assertions on mock:out because I publish on activemq:foo only if a certain condition is satisfied

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let Camel create your bean, then the various dependency injection and whatnot is configured for you.

```
private static BeanEndpoint beanEndpoint

 ...

beanEndpoint = camelContext.getInjector().newInstance(BeanEndpoint.class);
```